# Run javascript with canvas as an executable file

Tags: javascript, executable

I'm curious.

I have been making a game with some friends of mine, and i kind of promised that we could build it in javascript against canvas and make it an installable file. At that moment my plan was appjs, but I'm starting to see problems with that selection so now I'm here.

So is there any ways to make a game as an .exe file or similar where the code is in JavaScript interacting with the screen in the same way it should a canvas in a browser?

Comment: Check this out http://www.phpied.com/make-your-javascript-a-windows-exe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Chromium embedded](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) inside of a .Net, Java or python program.

[Bracket.io](http://brackets.io/) is using Chromium embedded for their text editor (Brackets) written in html, css and javascript.

Or if you are more the .Net type of guy, you could use a Browser control inside of a Windows Forms application.

Update: there's also Bracket Shell:
http://clintberry.com/2013/html5-desktop-apps-with-brackets-shell/

Comment: yes im a .NET guy
Btw do you know the difference between the .Net, .Net (CEF1) and .Net/Mono (CEF3). I'm guessing that last one keeps cross platform via mono. Thinking of Chromium embedded btw

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the difference. But I have used the CefSharp library in a test project and am quite happy with the results.

Comment: sounds like its worth a shot, I'm testing appjs atm but i cant really compile it. thats why I'm asking.